# How this can be done in more perl way

Tags: perl

I'm a novice in Perl and for one of my homework I came up with a solution like this :

```
#wordcount.pl FILE 
    # 

    #if no filename is given, print help and exit 
    if (length($ARGV[0]) < 1) 
    { 
           print "Usage is : words.pl word filename\n"; 
           exit; 
    } 

   my $file = $ARGV[0];          #filename given in commandline 

   open(FILE, $file);            #open the mentioned filename 
   while(<FILE>)                 #continue reading until the file ends 
    { 
           chomp; 
           tr/A-Z/a-z/;          #convert all upper case words to lower case 
           tr/.,:;!?"(){}//d;            #remove some common punctuation symbols 
           #We are creating a hash with the word as the key.  
           #Each time a word is encountered, its hash is incremented by 1. 
           #If the count for a word is 1, it is a new distinct word. 
           #We keep track of the number of words parsed so far. 
           #We also keep track of the no. of words of a particular length.  

          foreach $wd (split) 
          { 
                $count{$wd}++; 
                if ($count{$wd} == 1) 
                 { 
                       $dcount++; 
                 } 
                $wcount++; 
                $lcount{length($wd)}++; 
          } 
   } 

   #To print the distinct words and their frequency,  
   #we iterate over the hash containing the words and their count. 
   print "\nThe words and their frequency in the text is:\n"; 
   foreach $w (sort keys%count) 
   { 
         print "$w : $count{$w}\n"; 
   } 

   #For the word length and frequency we use the word length hash 
   print "The word length and frequency in the given text is:\n"; 
   foreach $w (sort keys%lcount) 
   { 
         print "$w : $lcount{$w}\n"; 
   } 

   print "There are $wcount words in the file.\n"; 
   print "There are $dcount distinct words in the file.\n"; 

   $ttratio = ($dcount/$wcount)*100;       #Calculating the type-token ratio. 

   print "The type-token ratio of the file is $ttratio.\n";
```

I have included the comment to mention what it does. Actually I have to find the word count from the given text file. The output of the above program will look like :

```
The words and their frequency in the text is: 
1949 : 1
a : 1
adopt : 1
all : 2
among : 1
and : 8
assembly : 1
assuring : 1
belief : 1
citizens : 1
constituent : 1
constitute : 1
.
.
.
The word length and frequency in the given text is:
1 : 1
10 : 5
11 : 2
12 : 2
2 : 15
3 : 18
There are 85 words in the file. 
There are 61 distinct words in the file. 
The type-token ratio of the file is 71.7647058823529.
```

Even though with the help of Google I can able to find out the solution for my homework. But however I think that there will be a smaller and concise code using the real power of Perl. Can anyone give me a solution in Perl with much less lines of code?

Comment: According to your usage statement, the file name is the second argument.  That contradicts your code.

Comment: Suggestion one is: do not use open explicitly.  Just use <>.  Perl will interpret each argument in ARGV as a filename, and <> will read from it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell : Yes file name is the second argument..

Comment: Since I'm a novice, I came up with this ;) Feel free to give concise perl way of doing it ;)

Comment: As it is homework, we're commited to _hinting_ you :)

Comment: @Laurent' : well its a great comment :) i finished my homework. But now I want to know how Perl can be used in more concise way. Thats what I need.

Comment: The program is pretty good.  You should use strict and use warnings, and the 3 argument open with a variable for the file handle.  The separate hash to count distinct words is not needed, you can just say "$dcount = keys %count;" to get the unique word count at the end.

Comment: Also, while for just one argument direct manipulation of `@ARGV` is OK, I would strongly recommend getting into the habit of always parsing command line parameters via `GetOpt::Long` module (this is independent of whether this specific task needed command line argument processing vs `<>` in the first place)

Comment: @DVF : Can you give an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are several suggestions:

- Include `use strict` and `use warnings` in your Perl scripts.
- Your argument validation isn't testing what it should be testing: (1) whether there is exactly 1 item in `@ARGV`, and (2) whether that item is a valid file name.
- Although there are exceptions to every rule, it's generally good practice to assign the return from `<>` to a named variable, rather than relying on `$_`. This is particularly true if the code inside the loop might need to use one of Perl's constructs that also relies on `$_` (for example, `map`, `grep`, or post-fix `for` loops)

  ```
  while (my $line = <>){
      ...
  }
  ```
- Perl provides a built-in function (`lc`) to lowercase strings.
- You are performing unnecessary computations inside the line reading loop. If you simply build up a tally of words, you'll have all of the information you need. Also note that Perl offers a one-liner form for most of its control structures (`for`, `while`, `if`, etc.), as illustrated below.

  ```
  while (my $line = <>){
      ...
      $words{$_} ++ for split /\s+/, $line;
  }
  ```
- You can then use the word tallies to compute the other information you need. For example, the number of unique words is simply the number of keys in the hash and the total number of words is the sum of the hash values.
- The distribution of word lengths can be computed like this:

  ```
  my %lengths;
  $lengths{length $_} += $words{$_} for keys %words;
  ```

Comment: Postfix loops are the #1 syntax abomination in a language full of syntax abominations

Comment: ohhh! Looks like Perl cookbook kind of examples :) I have some doubts, `$words{$_} ++ for split /\s+/, $line;` what exactly this is doing? I couldn't able to figure out why `$words{$_}` used in this fashion, what is exactly `$_` for?

Comment: @GroovyUser It's just a shortened form of `for (split /\s+/, $line){ $words{$_} ++ }`, where `$_` is an individual word.

Comment: @FMc : And the code you mentioned `scalar(keys %words);`, where what is `scalar` and what this code returns? And what I understood from your comment is, for the code `word{$_}++`. The `++` is the `value` for `key`, right? If the `line` has lets say `very good very good`, the first step will be `words{very}` and hence `very` is new it will be incremented to 1 and after processing  the whole statement `very` and `good` count will be `2`. Am I correct? *_O

Comment: @GroovyUser Yes, you are interpreting the code correctly -- but just to be sure, create a small test script and try it out yourself ... do some experimenting `:)`. Regarding `scalar`, you can look it up at http://perldoc.perl.org/ or with `perldoc -f scalar` on your command line.

Comment: @FMc : Yes playing with the experimentation part and having fun with it :) thanks for the answer. It was an excellent homework :)

Comment: @Nemo, I like the postfix loops when you only are doing one thing in the loop. There are other languages, go use one you like better.

Comment: @Joel:  I like my computer to do things in the order I tell it to.  I actually use Perl quite a bit; I just avoid writing line noise like this

Comment: You do not need to reassign `$_` to `$line` as long as you are confident about it's scoping. `for (qw(a b c)) { say "Main loop: $_"; say for (1,2,3); say "After: $_"; }` will behave exactly as expected. The inner loop will create a localized version of `$_`, and after it goes out of scope, the old `$_` will be in effect.

Comment: @TLP True enough, but my advice to the OP isn't mainly about scoping. A named variable has the advantage of being self-documenting. Also, it's required whenever the logic inside the loop uses a postfix `for`, `grep`, or `map` that needs to use the line.

Comment: If by that you mean "use `$line` inside the postfix loop". `say for split` for example will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using hashes like you are is a good way to go about it. A more perl way to parse the file is to use a regex with the /g flag to read words from the line. `\w+` means one or more alphanumerics.

```
while( <FILE> )
{
    while( /(\w+)/g )
    {
        my $wd = lc( $1 );
        ...

     }
 }
```